# How to center text in mobile layout?

Tags: html, css

I made a landing page that centers the text on it and it looks fine on a desktop layout but when I change to mobile layout, it looks like this:

[image]

Code:

```
 <div class="container-fluid" style="position: relative; top: 50%;">
                <center>
                    <div class="container" >

                        <h1 >A home is made of <i>
                                             <p >hopes</p>
                            </i> and <i>
                                <p >dreams</p>
                            </i>
                        </h1>


                        <h1>Let us<i>
                                <p >inspire</p>
                            </i> you to build the perfect home!
                        </h1> <br>
                    </div>

                    <a href="/login "  class="btn grad1" style="margin-right:20px; font-size:20px; "><b>{{ __('LOGIN') }}</b></a>
                    <a href="/register"  class="btn grad1" style="margin-left:20px; font-size:20px;"><b>{{ __('SIGN UP') }}</b></a>

                    <div class="container-fluid" style="position: absolute; left:60%; top:-150%;">
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried using `text-align property` to center but it does not change the alignment.

Comment: I tried on fiddle and it's working fine! on mobile which browser are you using?

Comment: Actually I am emulating it on chrome developer tools with iphone X layout. Tried it there.

Comment: You should not be using `<center>` with HTML5, also seems to be your use of `position: absolute` is unnecessary and definitely will make things harder for your layout.... Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @IvanS95 No, no bootstrap. Yea, I am actually fixing my colleague's bad code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't know for sure, but you are using a lot of styles and tags that seem to be making your layout much more difficult, you are also using tags that should no longer be used with HTML5 (specifically the `<center>` tag).

I removed some of the containers, the `position: absolute` properties, the excessive `<p>` tags and just added the `text-align: center` property to the main container and that's enough to align the text on any screen.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <h1>
    A home is made of
    <p><i>hopes</i> and <i>dreams</i></p>

    <p>Let us <i>inspire</i> you to build the perfect home!</p>
  </h1>
  <br>
</div>

<div class="buttons-row">
  <a href="/login " class="btn grad1" style="margin-right:20px; font-size:20px; "><b>{{ __('LOGIN') }}</b></a>
  <a href="/register" class="btn grad1" style="margin-left:20px; font-size:20px;"><b>{{ __('SIGN UP') }}</b></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution removing uneccesary stuff but the buttons went off the grid as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding style to the div container like this:

```
<div class="container" style="align-text: center"></div>
```

Comment: Then try align-content:center.